# Google Compute Engine - troubleshooting SSH default port

Tags: linux, ssh, google-compute-engine

when running

```
gcutil ssh myproject_name
```

ssh run with the following command

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/MyUser/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 22 MyUser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

i've changed my ssh port to 1234 in `sshd_config` file and opened a `firewall rule` at my compute engine console. executing the following command works perfect and connection is established

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/MyUser/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 1234 MyUser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

but when running this command `gcutil ssh myproject_name` port 22 is being called.

How & where can i change the default port of ssh so I wont have to use the long command in order to connect to my instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcutil` supports alternate ports via the `--ssh_port` flag. In your case, this should work:

```
gcutil ssh --ssh_port 1234 INSTANCE_NAME
```

Comment: your answer works but it doesn't change the default port. after executing your command if i try running `gcutil ssh myInstanceName` it still tries connecting over **port 22**